# Was Ganga mentioned in Rig Veda VI.45.31 the river Ganga?

Tags: rig-veda, ganga

Rig Veda [VI.45.31](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06045.htm) says

> adhi bṛbuḥ paṇīnāṃ varṣiṣṭhe mūrdhannasthāt | uruḥ kakṣo na ghāṅghyaḥ
>   ||
>
> Brbu hath set himself above the Paṇis, o’er their highest head, Like
>   the wide bush on Gangā's bank.

My question here -  **Was Ganga mentioned in this mantra, the river Ganga?**

Answer (score 1):

> uruḥ kakṣo na **ghāṅghyaḥ** ||

The correct verse is probably [this](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/1_veda/1_sam/1_rv/rvh1-10u.htm):

> RV_6,045.31a   adhi bṛbuḥ paṇīnāṃ varṣiṣṭhe mūrdhann asthāt | 
>   RV_6,045.31c   uruḥ kakṣo na **gāṅgyaḥ** ||

Based on the context, *wide* ([*uru*](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/uru/42450/1)) and *girth* or *bank* (*[kakṣa](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/kak%E1%B9%A3a/47169/1)*), etc. the verse appears to be referring to the river.

R. L. Kashyap [translates it](https://vedah.com/product/rig-veda-samhita-mandala-6/) the same way:

> 6.45.31: Bṛbu presided over the powerful places of the Paṇis, like **the wide bank of the Ganges**.
>
> [  *varṣhiṣhthe*: most powerful, (5.7.1); According to Sāyaṇa, Bṛbu is a divine artisan (*takṣha*). The three mantras 31-33 deal with his gifts. Bṛbu obtained his possessions from the Paṇis for doing their work. Recall that Paṇis are the traffickers in the powers of senses. ]

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. River ganga is mentioned in ***nadi stuti*** which mentions several rivers.

- Rigveda 10:75:5

> Favour ye this my laud,**O Gangā,** Yamunā, O Sutudri, Paruṣṇī and Sarasvatī:
>   With Asikni, Vitasta, O Marudvrdha, O Ārjīkīya with Susoma hear my call.

- Rigveda 6:45:31

> Brbu hath set himself above the Paṇis, o’er their highest head,
>   Like the wide bush on **Gan!gā's** bank.